# Perl scripts hogging CPU

Tags: perl, memory, cpu, suse

I am running several instances of a script and everything works fine.
Each terminal I load builds CPU higher though.

I am running 12 instances and throttling 99% of a dual core CPU.
I fully stacked my ram 8gb of DDR3.
At one point during the project, I used mysql but found heavy bottlenecks there and some random disconnect error (which googling told me could be the NIC).

Anyways..So writing to disc was a lot quicker straight from shell.
The module used is WWW:Mechanize

As far as per instance though,the profile isn't terrible. Bounces up-down to 24%. But I reach a limit in execution to 100% load with 8 or 9 terminal windows running.. Most likely it is a result of bandwidth and just download time.. Could I speed this up at all? Let's say stop downloading after a # of kilobytes ?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: what the heck are these scripts doing? What are you talking about when referring to "pushing more onto RAM and off CPU"? They're not interchangeable resources at all.

Comment: You seem to be very confused. Please take the perspective of someone who is not intimately familiar with what you are trying to do, and pose your question so that such a person can understand both your goals and constraints. Besides, why would you want your CPU to be idle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not believe there is a way to affect the perl interpreter behaviour that way. You can set up cpu limits for all your perl scripts on your box, but as far as I know, there is no way to do that in perl, as the interpreter manages all memory allocation etc. on its own.

You may want to check out this link: [How to limit CPU usage in perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=745869)

Also you may want to look into perl's threads, as that will definitely be more efficient then running the interpreter for 19 times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Hmm. Well what about the module. It is WWW:Mechanize.. Thoughts to better utilize this? Are the alternatives better e.g Curl,LWP?

Comment: You can run the script under `Devel::NYTProf` and see where your script is actually spending CPU time. Profiling!

Comment: WWW::Mechanize module is deemed to be the best one for web processing. As for alternatives, Mechanize is a subclass of LWP, so Mechanize only provides little better handling of the data. For more assistance you may want to post the actual script in question. 
@fennec: Good point!+1

Comment: These are terrific suggestions, thanks! As far as per instance though,the profile isn't terrible. Bounces up-down to 24%. But I reach a limit in execution to 100% load with 8 or 9 terminal windows running.. Most likely it is a result of bandwidth and just download time.. Could I speed this up at all? Let's say stop downloading after a # of kilobytes ?

Comment: I found especial use out of Cyber-Guard Design's suggestion with threading.  This concept seems new in Perl and I checked it out.  Could allow a source for improvement in my code. Thanks to all involved!

Answer (score 1):

> But I reach a limit in execution to
>   100% load with 8 or 9 terminal windows
>   running.. Most likely it is a result
>   of bandwidth and just download time..

Umm...  No.  If you hit a wall due to bandwidth constraints/download time, then your processes will block on I/O (process status `D` in `top`/`ps`) and effectively go to sleep, consuming next-to-no CPU cycles until the I/O request completes.

As for what your current problem is, that's impossible to say without more details about what your code is doing, ideally including source code, but a general description of your algorithms may well be sufficient.

Do note, though, that with 8 or 9 processes running, you're guaranteed to peg the CPU at 100% if a single instance averages any more than 11-12% CPU usage.  You haven't said anything about average per-process CPU consumption, but, if it regularly bounces up to 24%, then I wouldn't be at all surprised to find that it averages half that or higher.

Comment: Dave thank you for the input(I enjoyed your website as well). Let's keep this general as I am convinced my inexperience is the key. Obviously it is simple math when running that many terminals at 24% each spiking 100% after 4 is probable. There are several ideas I have in mind but alas, time time time. FYI though I found a fantastic command "last" in for loops which is awesome!

Comment: For anyone interested I found a great solution to my problem(in part). When using RAND() on a mysql server, I had to index over 300,000 records each time! I knew RAND() was inefficient at this scale but couldn't find an alternative (tried generating prior requests in Perl which hogged the client side down).. Alas.. Until...  "select id from `converge` where rand() > .9 order by rand() limit 1;" This query took 90% overhead off my queries! The question I still have is, why ? :)

Comment: @Peter: Oh, well, then, that explains it, yes... When you use `RAND` in a query, the database has to generate a random value for every row in the table, even if it only returns one row in the end. Worse, if you're going to `ORDER BY RAND`, it then has to sort the rows on an unindexed value, which is a relatively expensive operation. By adding the `WHERE RAND > .9`, it's now generating 330k random numbers, but it only has to sort 30k unindexed values, since the 90% or records where the first `RAND` returns .9 or less get discarded before the `ORDER BY` is processed.